# Leadbolt In App Popup Ads, Creating A Timed Popup With Iframe and A close Button

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

i currently have a music application, and I'm trying to ad lead bolts inapp ad wall they don't give you any help on this what so ever. all they put is

Place this link in a webview of your app or an iframe of your mobile web page where you want your LeadBolt app wall to appear.

http://ad.leadboltads.net/show_app_wall?section_id=97********

im a novice when it comes to programming

I've asked about and I've researched for hours and i haven't been able to find a solution all i can get is mixed answers

all i am really after is a simple timed popup with a web browser in it with an iframe which calls that address so its runs the ad until its closed then pops up again after an x amount of time, is this the best way to solve this or is there another way

i don't mean to be rude but could who ever answers, answer with detail because like i said I'm a novice thanks in advance

EDIT*

i have just found this on there site 
 Add the following line in your XAML file
    webview height="50" width="320" x:name="webview">

Then in your xaml.cs file add the following code to load a HTML Banner or HTML App Wall
webview.NavigateToString("http://ad.leadboltads.net/show_app_ad.js?section_id=xxxxxxxxx\">");

// For App Wall use the following code:
// webview.Navigate(new Uri("http://ad.leadboltads.net/show_app_wall?section_id=xxxxxxxx"));

my new question is how do i get it to appear every so often, above everything else until user closes it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting your question. Our tech team at LeadBolt has supplied the following suggestions to help you out.

If you require further assistance I would encourage you to contact your Account Manager directly, or email our Support team.

```
To Add a simple auto-refreshing HTML Banner:

1.       In your xaml file, add a WebView object like so: <WebView x:Name="banner"     Width="320" Height="50" />
2.       Add the following code in your xaml.cs file. Please note this is just a sample code, please modify the class and method names as suited to your App’s xaml.cs file:

namespace HTMLAdDemo
{
            public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
            {
                            private DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
                            String bannerHtml = “<html><body style=\”margin:0;padding:0\”><script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://ad.leadboltads.net/show_app_ad.js?section_id=YOUR_LB_SECTION_ID\"></script></body></html>”;

                            public MainPage()
{
            this.InitializeComponent();
            banner.NavigateToString(bannerHtml);

                                            // now setup timer to refresh banner every 30s
                                            timer.Tick += (sender, e) => { bannerWebview.NavigateToString(bannerHtml); };
                                            timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(00, 0, 30); //change this number to modify the refresh time
timer.Start();
}
                            // Your other App Specific functions here
            }
}
```

To Add an App Wall with a close button. Please Note: this is just a sample code, actual implementation may vary in your App to suit your App’s requirement (i.e Colours, Text and Style need to be modified based on your App’s Requirements):

```
1.       In your xaml file, add the following objects:


<WebView x:Name="appWall" Width="400" Height="300" />
<Button x:Name="closeButton" Width="400" Height="40" Content="Close"     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Click="Button_Click"/>

2.       Add the following code in your xaml.cs file. Please note this is just a sample     code, please modify the class and method names as suited to your App’s xaml.cs file

namespace HTMLAdDemo
{
            public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
            {
                            public MainPage()
{
            this.InitializeComponent();

            appWall.Navigate(new Uri("http://ad.leadboltads.net/show_app_wall?section_id=YOUR_LB_SECTION_ID"));

}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        appWall.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        closeButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}

                            // Your other App Specific functions here
                }
}
```

Kind Regards,

LeadBolt Support